# Golang - Cannot infer T from interface implementation?

Tags: go, generics, interface

Say I have the following code:

```golang
type Getter[T any] interface {
    Get() T
}

type Wrapper[T any] struct {
    a T
}

func (s Wrapper[T]) Get() T {
    return s.a
}
```

Here, you can say that `Wrapper[T]` implements `Getter[T]` - since it implements `Get() T` which is the only requirement.

Now, I have a function that needs to take a `Getter[T]` in order to return the internal value...

```golang
func Return[T any](i Getter[T]) T {
    return i.Get()
}

var s1 = Wrapper[int]{
    a: 5,
}
```

Here, `Return` just gets the value inside - so the expectation is that when I pass in `s1`, I should get `5` in return.

```golang
var s2 = Return(s1) // type Wrapper[int] of s1 does not match Getter[T] (cannot infer T)
```

...instead, I get that error. Now, there is an easy workaround here...

```golang
func (s Wrapper[T]) Getter() Getter[T] {
    return s
}

var s2 = Return(s1.Getter())
```

This ends up working. `Getter()` does nothing but return itself - functionally speaking, `s1` and `s1.Getter()` should be identical here - and yet it doesn't work. `T` can be inferred in the method, but not as a parameter.

My question is this: Am I doing something wrong here - or is this just a part of Go? For this example to work, do I need to add a dummy method just to help the compiler - or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to add methods to `Wrapper`, but if [type inference](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_inference) does not succeed (the compiler can't infer all types), you have to provide the types for the type parameters explicitly, like this:

```
var s2 = Return[int](s1)
```

The `Return()` function has a type parameter, if you provide the type for `T` explicitly (`int` here), then the compiler will be able to validate that `s1` does indeed implement the `Getter[int]` interface. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/zIeZJHgfiqs).